# Symfony 5 - HttpClient, Add "Authorization bearer 123456789azertyuiop" in headers data

Tags: php, api, symfony, http-headers, symfony-http-client

I would like to attach authentication information in the header of an HTTP request using HttpClientInterface.
(*I already have 45 other methods that work very well*) but my problem occurs when I **try to send a file** with the **multipart/form-data content-type**.
I take the code from the original [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#uploading-data) below to stay on a very simple case but I can't join my data in the generated ones.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\DataPart;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Part\Multipart\FormDataPart;
    
$formFields = [
    'regular_field' => 'some value',
    'file_field' => DataPart::fromPath('/path/to/uploaded/file')
];
$formData = new FormDataPart($formFields);
$client->request('POST', 'https://...', [
    'headers' => $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray(),
    'body' => $formData->bodyToIterable(),
]);
```

Here's what I'm trying to do

```php
$myHeader = [
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->getUser()->getToken()
];
$params = [
    'headers' => array_merge($myHeader, $formData->getPreparedHeaders()->toArray()),
    'body'    => $formData->bodyToIterable(),
];
```

And here's how it's translated so the API doesn't understand what I send it and return me back a **400 bad request**

```php
"headers" => [
    "Authorization" => "Bearer eecd39xxxxxxxxede8e66433d3aea693"
    0 => "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ujDYAsPF"
]
```

It's a relatively common case in principle so I guess there is a solution?  thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you're looking for `auth_bearer`. This one is mentioned in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_client.html#authentication).

So the request would look something like the following...

```
$httpClient->request("GET", "/the/request/path", [
    'auth_bearer' => $this->getUser()->getToken()
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `getPreparedHeaders` you have to add your own headers to the `Header` object it returns and then use `toArray()` to pass it to your request.

```
$formData = new FormDataPart($data);
$header = $formData->getPreparedHeaders();
$header->addTextHeader('Authorization',  "Bearer $token");
```

It will give you the proper key/value header

```
"headers" => [
    "Authorization" => "Bearer eecd39xxxxxxxxede8e66433d3aea693"
    "Content-Type" => "multipart/form-data; boundary=ujDYAsPF"
]
```